# What does the {% raw %} tag do in Ionic's todo list tutorial?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm looking into Ionic and Angularjs and I noticed something in a [a tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html) that isn't really explained.

```
{% raw %}
```

I found [this post](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/puzzled-at-the-raw-markup-in-the-todo-tutorial/10446) on the official ionic forums but it doesn't really elaborate.

Does that mean it shouldn't be in the example at all? Is the tag needed to correct a formatting issue with the code below it? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What he means in his forum answer:

You can completely ignore this.  the {% raw %} is part of the code that renders the ionic website (it looks like specifically for their code blocks).

So continue on with the tutorial and pretend like it's not there.

Comment: Ah, page markup for their tutorial page itself. I should have figured that! Cheers